# springboot google oauth2 and authorization from backend

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0, authorization

I develops a some RestController and I'm using something like

```
@PreAuthorize(“hasRole(‘ADMIN')”)
```

for the authorization.

I'm using oauth (google API) for the authentification. And I would like used own DB for authorization (managed and other user data).
What are good practices ? How can I resolved this issue (may use filter) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your own database for authentication then you can make use of UserDetailsService interface which is used in order to lookup the username, password and GrantedAuthorities for any given user.

This interface provide only one method which implementing class need to implement-

```
UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;
```

1. Create a class which implements this interface and override a above method to get the user details from your DB.(Annotate this class with @Service annotation) Here you can call your DB to get the users details by provided userName and convert it to UserDetails.
2. Create a custom MyUserdetails class which implements UserDetails interface. And implement all required methods.
3. Now create a class say SecurityConfiguration which extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter annotate this class with @EnableWebSecurity.(The @EnableWebSecurity is a marker annotation. It allows Spring to find (it's a @Configuration and, therefore, @Component) and automatically apply the class to the global WebSecurity.) In this class autowire UserDetailsService bean and override a following method to get users details from your DB.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }
```

4. Add following dependency in you pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

5. Also annotate you main class with following annotation to let spring know that you are using JPA

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
```

Hope this helps.